# TFS 2018 update 2 upgrade: Reporting Services

Tags: tfs

Origin machine: TFS 2017 update 3 & SQL Server 2014

Destination machine: TFS 2018 update 2 & SQL Server 2017

Steps followed for a Dry-Run:

1. Followed the ["Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=vsts) and ["Do a dry run of your upgrade"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/upgrade/pre-production). All databases are successfully restored on the same server (TFS_configuration, Tfs_collections, Tfs_Warehouse, ReportServer, ReportServerTempDB, Tfs_Analysis).
2. ChangeServerId and RemapDBs executed successfully.
3. When running the wizard to use the "Pre-production Upgrade Testing" we noticed the following:

   - When using "< nameofserver >\SSRS" (this is the default instance name for Reporting Services in SQL Server 2017) on "Reporting Services Instance" and the correct URLs are selected, these errors appear on the Readiness Checks:

> *It appears that the following best practices for this scenario have 
>   not been implemented:   VS403144: The warehouse database is currently pointing to the same database that was being used on your production deployment.
>
>   VS403140: The specified Analysis Services database is the same one being used in your production deployment.*

- When using "< nameofserver >" (this has been used in the past successfully with tfs2017) on "Reporting Services Instance" the following message pops up:

> *TF255186: The following SQL Server Reporting Services Instance could not be found: MSSQLSERVER. The server name is: "< nameoftheserver >"*

Is the change of the instance name from "MSSQLSERVER" to "SSRS" causing this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Daniel's answer ? any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because you **don't need to use ChangeServerID and ReMapDBs** with the
Pre-production Upgrade Testing scenario. That scenario does those operations for you.

I'd reset the test instance, restore the databases, and try again without running changeserverID/remapDBs.